# jQuery $.post to INSERT sql via php not working

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax, post

Simply trying to update my sql database via php and jquery ajax.  It is loading the Unique ID so I know it is passing through to the database, its just that there is no other data that it is passing.

For my first page:

```
<script>
$.post("kpi.php", { orders: '15'}, function(data) {
alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
});     
</script>
```

This returns "Data Loaded: 0" and adds a unique ID to the database with 'ORDERS' blank.

Here is kpi.php:

```
<?php 
$con = mysql_connect("domain.fatcowmysql.com","user","pass");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("ga", $con);

mysql_query("INSERT INTO kpi (ORDERS) VALUES ('$orders')");

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

Any ideas on how to get that number "15" passed through to the database from my first page?

Comment: on the Table 'kpi' something is being updated but not the field ORDERS, just the unique ID that is auto populated when something is added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understood your question correctly,`$_POST['orders']` is what you want.

Comment: this gives a syntax error on `mysql_query("INSERT INTO kpi (ORDERS) VALUES $_POST['orders']");`

Comment: What's the data type for field 'ORDERS' in database?you probably need to add single quotes.`mysql_query("INSERT INTO kpi (ORDERS) VALUES '{$_POST['orders']}'")`

Answer (score 0):

This is I think what you're trying to do.

```
 $(document).ready(function() 
    {
    // Update Status
    $(".submit").click(function() 
    {
    var orders = $("#orders").val();
    var dataString = 'orders='+ orders;
    if(orders=='')
    {
    alert("Please Enter Some Text");
    }
    else
    {
    $("#flash").show();
    $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('Loading Update...');
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "kpi.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {
   alert('Success');    

      }
     });
    }
    return false;
        });


    $orders = mysql_escape_string($_POST['orders']);
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO kpi (ORDERS) VALUES ('$orders')");

    mysql_close($con);
```

Comment: I don't want to do a click function, this should be posted to the database when I open the page.